# Return Multiple Rows Based On A Value From Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that has 3 columns. Col1 is an identity column and sets to autoincrement. Now I want to return multiple rows based on a value in Col3, and the Col2 increments by 1.

For example, if I insert 25 in Col2 and 7 in Col3, I want an output similar to this one:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3
----   ----    ----
1       25       7    
2       26       7
3       27       7
4       28       7
5       29       7
6       30       7
7       31       7
```

I tried something using partition in my SELECT query, but still I didn't get the desired output. What do you think is the better way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output you are expecting?

Comment: If you don't describe what you try to do exactly we can't help you.

Comment: Richard, the sample above is the output I'm expecting....

Comment: juergen, what I want (my desired output) is the sample I gave above.

Comment: OK, so you want result grouped on Col3 (Col3=7 and Col3=3), and you want Col2 to increase by one in order of the Col1, indepndently for each group. What I miss is where do 25 and 50 (min values for Col2 for respective groups) come from?

Comment: Thanks, dean.... When I insert 25 in Col2 and 7 in Col3, it will produce multiple rows depending on the value in Col3.... Then Col2 will increment by 1.

Comment: Can't believe nobody has provided a solid answer to this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're looking for something like this:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col3, col1) AS col2, col3 FROM ...`

Provide more details if that doesn't fit.